# Как извлечь метаданные докуметов Microsoft Office и pdf?

Tags: метаданные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался со следующей проблемой. Мне нужно получить метаданные из докуметов  Microsoft Office (Word|Excel) и pdf. Интересует в первую очередь: Автор, Дата создания\изменения.
Воспользовался сначала консольной утилитой ExifTool, однако там проблема с выводом кириллицы. Какие средства для этого существуют помимо вышеперечисленных (если есть онлайн - вообще круто)? 
Желательно в свободном доступе (бюджет на покупку лицензии - 0:))

Comment: Непонятно на каком языке требуется... https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Будем изучать. Насчет языка, то без разницы... Я сегодня тоже обнаружил одну интересную штуку, но еще не разбирался. Вот, может кому-то еще пригодится https://github.com/ElevenPaths/FOCA .